# Springtime Ski Resorts near NYC

Tags: skiing, new-york-state

I am looking to plan two weekends near NYC with visiting ski resorts over the next few weeks. There is very little information I have found on spring skiing in NY, except that generally Hunter Mt should be open latest due to their best snow-making capacity.

However, currently checking the situation, it looks as if Hunter Mt has less snow than the other Catskills resorts -- Belleayre, Plattekill, and Windham. At the same time, Plattekill is reported more or less closed on some sites though [their website](https://www.plattekill.com/) mentions they will open for the upcoming Friday.

I have been using [OnTheSnow](https://www.onthesnow.com/new-york/skireport.html) and [OpenSnow](https://opensnow.com/state/NY) for these assessments which seem to give a better overview than the actual websites for these resorts.

Hence, my questions:

1. What order should the Catskills resorts be visited in to have the best chances for four days' skiing over the next two weeks? It doesn't look to me that any of these are large enough to stay at (unless, perhaps, there is no snow elsewhere...).
2. Alternatively, are there any other ski resorts near NYC (clarification: approx three hours' drive one way) that would offer a more immersive ski experience in March than the above-mentioned ones?

I'm afraid that this is slightly open to opinion, but I am hoping that people with actual experience of these places can offer some context to what the numbers on these overview sites mean for ground conditions.

Comment: I suppose you might not consider this immersive, but there's always [Big Snow American Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Snow_American_Dream) in the Meadowlands.  Being an indoor facility, it is not as susceptible to warm weather.

Comment: @phoog: Good one! I've never tried indoors options so this could be a very good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Killington VT always likes to boast the longest season in the north east, but may be a little far from NYC. I have enjoyed many spring skiing trips there (although I'm a little closer in Connecticut).

From midtown Manhattan, Killington is about a 250 mile (4.5 hour) drive.

Comment: Yesterday I also heard some people comment positively on Mt Snow in VT. In general, it seems that people don't recommend NY for this late into the season. Perhaps you could add an approximate distance from NY to your answer to make it more thorough?

Comment: @gktscrk the Vermont ski resorts are more comparable in distance to the Adirondacks than the Catskills.  I've never been to the Adirondacks, but I suspect they have later seasons there, too.  If you're willing to go that far (both the Adirondacks and Vermont are farther than three hours), you might want to look at both.

Comment: @phoog: Mt Snow in the Green Mountains is about an hour closer to the Adirondacks and the Killington area; seems to be an acceptable compromise. Another part of this should deal with the roads of course as most rental cars are probably without snow tires and from what I remember of the Adirondacks roads in August, that could be a problem.

Comment: @gktscrk I haven't been to Mt. Snow this late in the season, but I have been to Killington.  Mt. Snow is considerably higher, so it might indeed be acceptable.  I don't know how late Snow stays open.  Killington builds up a huge pile of snow on the main run from the summit so they can stay open as late as possible into the spring (as noted in this answer).  To what extent other runs stay open longer than Mt. Snow I cannot say.

Comment: Thanks @gktscrk - I updated my answer with approximate distance.